# How can i simulate this circuit to match with the truth table?

Tags: digital-logic, logic-gates, boolean-algebra, nand

[image][How can I simulate this NAND logic circuit to match the truth table?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63191.png)][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63191.png)

Comment: Are you looking for a program to simulate a digital circuit?

Answer (score 0):

> How can i simulate this circuit to match with the truth table?

Given the red lines in every second inverter in your screengrab (please turn off the grid next time) it looks as though you have a simulator running already.

Toggle each of the inputs to test the output.